# ssmtp cannot email my bash variable received from python subprocess

Tags: python, bash, subprocess, ssmtp

I'm using subprocess within a python script to send variables into a bash script which is designed to send emails.

**My python code:**

```
import re
import subprocess
message="https://example.com/"
subprocess.run(["./send_email.bash",message])
```

**My "./send_email.bash" script:**

```
#!/bin/bash
body=$1
echo "$body" | ssmtp example@gmail.com
```

It keeps sending a blank email. However, if I use a string which doesn't come from subprocess, the email contains it. There may be a better way of doing this, but the point of my post is to understand why this doesn't work. What perplexes me is that the variable sent from subprocess may be appended to a file. But, it cannot be recognized by loops or "if" expressions. etc.

Thank you!

Comment: Why don't you run `ssmtp` directly and feed the mail into its `stdin`? Or just use the `stmp` module to do what `ssmtp` does?

Comment: I did, it works. But I'm itching to figure out why this doesn't work. Thanks!

Comment: I should have been more specific. The "message" within my python code was an email address: "https://example.com/". It appears that when I remove the "https://" from the string, it works perfectly fine!

Comment: (You don't really need a shell script to send email; Python has `smtplib` and the `email` module for this purpose; or you could run `subprocess.run(['ssmtp'], input='your message')` -- but "your message" is not a valid email message, which you have to also provide, as noted in my comment on the answer).

Answer (score 0):

I should have been more specific. The "message" within my python code was an email address: "https://example.com/". It appears that when I remove the "https://" from the string, it works perfectly fine!

Comment: The real explanation is that anything with a colon in it gets interpreted as a header. The input to `ssmtp` should be a well-formed RFC5322 message, not some random string data. Try `printf '%s\n' "Subject: (no subject)" "" "$body" | ssmtp example@example.com` (also note [When to wrap quotes around a shell variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10067266/when-to-wrap-quotes-around-a-shell-variable))